# FTP, формат строки в ответе команде LIST

Tags: list, ftp-сервер, реализация

Делаю для своего контроллера простой FTP-сервер. Тестирую с помощью Filezilla, клиент не правильно интерпретирует ответ на команду LIST.

Отправляю с сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Клиент отображает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Месяц, число и год слились с именем файла и директории. Что я делаю не так?